# Set flag to one if the date imported is the max value

Tags: ssis

I am importing data in a table which has for example `importID, itemid, importDate, CurrentFlag` fields. I need to set `CurrentFlag` to true when the row imported has a `(max)importDate`. I am using the slowly changing dimension, where importDate is the Historical attribute and `CurrentFlag` the current record column. This updates any new record, not only the one which has a `(max)importDate`. How can i update the `CurrentFlag` only when `importDate` is greater than every `importDate` already stored in the table?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the update sql command in the oledb command task produced by the slowly changing dimension. There you can modify the sql statement to get and update anything/anyhow you like.